# Adding month in YYYYMM date format in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to add months in YYYYMM format, as part of one stored procedure. But could not find any add function for this kind of date format. Below is the scenario:

```
A      B         Output
-----------------------
01   202010      202011
02   202011      202101
03   202011      202102
04   202012      202104
```

I tried adding months in the year but it keeps adding months instead of changing the year value i.e. 202014, 202015.

Need your help to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Date and date-time values **do not have a "format"** inside a computer. Dates and times are not stored as strings. What is the nature of your input data? Are you wanting to write individual `INSERT INTO` statements, are you using a table-valued parameter? Or using SSIS? Is there any application code (PHP, VB, C#, Java, etc) that will be doing the insert?

Comment: " But could not find any add function for this kind of date format." Because it's not a date, it's a month. You should store Date values, not ints or strings. Then, display (or select) whatever you want, and this will become a non-issue.

Comment: And, as Dai wrote - [DateTime has no format.](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/for-the-1024-time-datetime-has-no-format/)

Comment: *Why* do you want to store month to begin with? There may be other ways to solve the problem. If you want this for reporting, a common technique is to [use a Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) with prepopulated dates for eg 20 years, and explicit columns for year, month, day, week number, *year-month*, start of month, end of month etc. Finding all records in a month becomes a simple join, filtered by the year and month, or Year-month fields. Finding the next month, add 1 month to StartOfMontth

Comment: If you want to compare values month-over-month, you can use the [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples)  analytic function to get next month's values. That's shown in the documentation examples. Something like `select YearMonth, Total, LEAD(Total,1,0) over (order by YearMonth) as NextTotal from SalesTable`

Comment: Hi Dai and Zohar, These both column A and B are of nvarchar type.

Comment: Basically I want this type of solution but it is not working in SSMS, as to_date function is not wokring there. tried to_char(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('202011','YYYYYMM'),4),'YYYYMM')

Comment: Are you saying that  `SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(MONTH, 4, CAST(CONCAT('202011','01') as DATE)),'yyyyMM')` as proposed in the answer below doesn't work in SQL Server?

Comment: user9601310: Thank you so much, It is working fine  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first converting your YYYYMM value to a Date by appending '01' to it. Then add your months value to the date using DATEADD, then format the date back to YYYYMM. Using your example above with columns A and B as the months-to-add and YYYYMM value respectively, the SQL below should give your desired values.

```
format(dateadd(month, A * 1, cast(concat(B, '01') as date)), 'yyyyMM') as new_yyyymm
```

Note: Your column A seems to be formatted as character, hence the "A * 1" above, to co-erce it to a number.